# Swift: how to remove a special character from a string?

Tags: swift, string, character, special-characters

I want to remove the special character `,` in a `string` so I can convert the value to a `double`. How do I do it?

Example:

```
let stringValue = "4,000.50";
```

I have tried to use the `NumberFormatter` but getting `nil` error

```
let NF = NumberFormatter();
let value = NF.number(from: stringValue);
//nil
```

Comment: Why not use a `NumberFormatter` to convert the string to a number?

Comment: it is saying nil @rmaddy

Comment: let stringValue = "4,000";  let NF = NumberFormatter(); let value = NF.number(from: stringValue); is NIL

Comment: What is? If you have trouble with code using a NumberFormatter, update your question with relevant code.

Comment: 1. Set the formatter's style. 2. What is your locale? 3. Will the string always have a comma or will the number string normally be formatted the same as the user's locale?

Comment: the string always contains a comma

Answer (score 3):

If the number string will always be formatted from a specific locale then you need to set the formatter's locale to match. Without setting the locale, the string won't be parsed if the user's locale using different grouping and decimal formatting.

```
let stringValue = "4,000.50"

let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let value = nf.number(from: stringValue)
```

FYI - this is Swift, you don't need semicolons at the end of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Same as @rmaddy but using string `replacingOccurrences` :

```
var stringValue = "4,000,000.50"
stringValue = stringValue.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

let nf = NumberFormatter()
let value = nf.number(from: stringValue)
print(value)
```

Comment: This won't work if the user's locale uses something other than `.` for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're working with currency, you could clean-up the text value for any decimal and thousand separator by leveraging the pattern of consecutive digits.  If there are any decimals, they would be the last group and would have exactly two digits (for most currencies).  On the basis of this assumption, you don't need to know which separator is used and you would also be resilient to the presence of other characters such as the currency name or symbol:

```
let textValue   = "Balance : 1 200,33 Euros"
let nonDigits   = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234456789").inverted
let digitGroups = textValue.components(separatedBy:nonDigits).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
let textNumber  = digitGroups.dropLast().joined(separator:"")
                + ( digitGroups.last!.characters.count == 2 
                    && digitGroups.count > 1 ? "." : "" )
                + digitGroups.last! 


textNumber // 1200.33
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a sanitized string with only digits and decimals, then in Xcode 9.0+ you can just do:

```
let originalString = "4,000.00"
let numberString = originalString.filter({ "1234567890.".contains($0) })

// numberString -> "4000.00"
```

Then, converting your sanitized string to a `Float` is as easy as

```
if let num = Float(numberString) {
    // do something with float
} else {
    // failed to init float with string
}
```